# Unsigned APK from Ionic 2 can't be installed on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created my first Ionic 2 app and ran:

```
cordova build --release android
```

I don't want to release the app now, just try to install it on my phone. But when doing so I get an error on my Galaxy S5 saying:

```
App not installed
```

This generated an unsigned APK file.

I don't have any further error details, so I have no idea where to start debugging. My phone accepts apps from unknown sources as I have installed many unsigned apps from PhoneGap Build already.

Any ideas?

Comment: As @Kaddath mentioned in answer, remove --release tag and try again. This will be development/debug APK so you can test it. The another option you can try is connect your device with USB debugging on and execute command `ionic run android`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `--release` option is to produce the final build (for release). Just remove this option for debugging.

Note that sometimes, some installations will fail if the debug application has been compiled on another machine and already installed on the device, in this case you need to uninstall it before trying to install.

If you have more problems leave a comment, i'll try to help.

Comment: in ionic 3 i tried to use flag --release and sign too.. but always force close when i install and opened...

Comment: @R.Drum I'm not sure what you mean, so you build your app for release, sign it and install on your device, then it crashes when you open it? If yes, then you should ask a separate question or comment on another post, this answer is about installation, if you successfully install your app it doesn't look relevant here, and I'm not sure I could help (not without more details anyway)